# Google map is doesn't display in meteor template

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

This is the script in header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=****&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Template

```
<template name="parentTemplate">
   {{> childTemplate}}
</template>
<template name="childTemplate">
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
Template.childTemplate.onRendered(function () {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: true
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
});
```

I doesnt get any error messages, but no map view in particular div.

Comment: It would be a lot easier for you to use a package. Try: https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps. There's also a tutorial here: http://meteorcapture.com/how-to-create-a-reactive-google-map/

Comment: Are you sure 'document' does exist in that context? Did you inspect the 'map-canvas'-element on your rendered page? Is it untouched?

Comment: a map needs a specified height, you sure you got it?

Comment: @Matt thanks Matt. I doesn't specify div height.